# Are Assumed Variables Safe to Use?

Tags: javascript, variables

I've always noticed that Chrome assumes variables based upon elements within an HTML document that have an ID.

For example, if I had `<video id="video" src="foo.webm"></video>` on my page, the variable "video" would be created automatically by the browser. No need to type out `var video = document.getElementById("video");`

Is this a standard browser feature? Is it something that is here with us to stay? Should I take advantage of this or be wary of it? I like it because it saves precious bytes, especially when you have a ton of element objects to define.

Comment: I never noticed this until now.

Answer (score -1):

Variables are not created that way.

document.getElementById("video") means you are selecting the "video" element, not variable. Checkout [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question.